# How to resolve failures in perl substitutions?

Tags: regex, macos, perl

A script that was working for some time has recently stopped working without any changes.  The diagnostic messages give the impression that the error is in perl, because they quote code that is NOT in my script!  The perl executable is dated 6 October, which is approximately when I first noticed the errors.

**Looking for any suggestions to resolve this.**

`~/bin/TC` is a script to clean up formatting in text:

```
#!/bin/zsh

perl -p -i -e 's:\r::g;
               s:(.*):<p>\1</p>:g;
               s:<p></p>::g;
               s:\':’:g;
               s:([\x27"]?[.?!][\x27"]?) :\1  :g;
               s:((”)?[.?!](”)?) :\1  :g;
               s:((’)?[.?!](’)?) :\1  :g;
               s:((»)?[.?!](»)?) :\1  :g;
               s:\*::g;
               s: - :—:g;
               s:- ::g;
               s:([.?!])’” :\1’”  :g;
               s:([.?!])”’ :\1”’  :g;'      $1
```

Here is the latest invocation and results:

```
WGroleau@MBP 013 % TC nl_parallel.txt
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
Scalar found where operator expected (Missing operator before "$!"?) at -e line 5, near ";}continue{print or die qq(-p destination: $!"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line :: string starting on line 4)
syntax error at -e line 5, near ";}continue{print or die qq(-p destination: $!"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
/Users/WGroleau/bin/TC:7: unknown file attribute: ?
```

Obviously, there IS a filename on the command line.  And, though there is a quote mark on line four, it is escaped, so it really doesn't start a string.  There is no "continue" in line five or any other line.  And the line seven reference makes no sense to me.

The quote on line four was not escaped when the script worked.  After it failed with the diagnostics shown (several times on different files), I added the backslash but it still gave the same messages.

perl 5, version 38, subversion 0 (v5.38.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
macOS 14.0 (23A344)

I didn't record exactly when the errors started, but it was approximately in the weeks that macOS, perl, and zsh were updated—late September & early October.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `zsh` for this? It has some quirks in how it handles quoting.

Comment: To get more information about the location of the error: Try to comment out one `s::`  line after another from the script until the error message disappears..

Comment: @tripleee, zsh has been the macOS default for some time.  I resisted at first, but eventually switched over.

Comment: Yes, it's the default interactive shell; but is there a reason not to use `/bin/sh` for a simple script like this?

Comment: Lacks detail?  The exact command that failed is in there, as well as the exact diagnostic messages.  AND it has a clear answer.  The answerer's apparent attitude problem does not invalidate the answer, as the change he/she proposed DID stop the errors.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is not special in shell single-quoted literals.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start of quoted part
#             |
#             v
perl -p -i -e 's:\r::g;
               s:(.*):<p>\1</p>:g;
               s:<p></p>::g;
               s:\':’:g;
#                 ^    ^
#                 |    |
# End of quoted part   End of shell command
               s:([\x27"]?[.?!][\x27"]?) :\1  :g;
               s:((”)?[.?!](”)?) :\1  :g;
               s:((’)?[.?!](’)?) :\1  :g;
               s:((»)?[.?!](»)?) :\1  :g;
               s:\*::g;
               s: - :—:g;
               s:- ::g;
               s:([.?!])’” :\1’”  :g;
               s:([.?!])”’ :\1”’  :g;'      $1
#                                    ^
#                                    |
#           Desired end of quoted part
```

Fix: Replace `\'` with `'\''` on the sixth line of the shell script.

(And note that `\1` (a regex atom that matches text captured earlier) should be `$1` (a variable containing text captured earlier) in the replacement expressions. Perl warns you about this.)

---

With the bug, you end up passing the following program to `perl`:

```perl
s:\r::g;
s:(.*):<p>\1</p>:g;
s:<p></p>::g;
s:\:’:g
```

As you can see, you have an unterminated `s:::` on the fourth line.

But `-p` wraps your code with the following:

```perl
LINE: while (<>) {...;}continue{print or die qq(-p destination: $!\n);}
```

Your otherwise unterminated `s:::` is terminated by the `:` in what should be an error message.

This explains the confusing error message, but it's correct about it being a "runaway multi-line :: string starting on line 4".